# Alternative To Pop Up Window

Tags: php, javascript, html, popup

I've put together a PHP script and small form which allows the user to upload image files. As it stands at the moment, this is activated as a Pop Up Window via a 'onclick' event of a button on the parent HTML page.

From research I've done on this site, I know that 'Pop Up Windows' aren't to everyones liking, so I'm really asking for a bit of advice to see whether there is an alternative to the Pop Up Window. I've tried the jQuery modal Dialog, and I've run into all sorts of problems because I have multiple submit buttons, so I'd rather not revsit that if at all possible, although the styling of the modal dialog would be along the right lines.

Comment: Describe "all sorts of problems because I have multiple submit buttons", because jquery modal dialog or another jquery solution is the way to go.

Comment: Why a popup window/dialog at all? Any way try fancybox or lightbox.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying to my post. Even after some excellent tuition from some members I couldn't get the 'submit' action on the main form i.e. submission of the complete form to work independently from the submission of the images I was uploading. Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'm a fan of JQuery UI Modal dialog because it's lightweight and I'm already loading UI in my apps.

But there's more going on here....the problem isn't the dialog, it's the fact that you're trying to do a file upload in a dialog.  The traditional method of uploading a file is via a $_POST.  This works just fine, except that your form needs an action, and that action will by default force a load of the page, even if you have it posting to itself.  So in practice, if you do uploads the traditional way, no modal dialog will work.

What you're probably looking for is to do the "Ajax" method of file upload.  It's not really ajax.....what you'd be doing is uploading to a "hidden" iFrame in the page that facilitates and upload seemingly without reload.  [Here's a tutorial](http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_ajax_example__asynchronous_file_upload.xml)...there's a million others out there.

There is also a number of jQuery plugins to make uploads easier....[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com) is just one of them.

Note that even if you use an "asynchronous" method, you're still under the limitations of HTML.  Having an upload button or an  `<input type="submit">` will submit your form, albeit not correctly, making the form seem like it's just failing uncontrollably.  So, to combat this, either setup your upload button as another non-form submit element such as an `<a>` or just an image with an id that you call onclick via javascript.  Or, make it a button and use `event.preventDefault()` onclick to prevent the default HTML behavior.  I generally do the latter with jQuery UI button styling.

Comment: Hi sincere thanks for taking the time to read and reply to my post. The links and your guidance are spot on! Once again many thanks and kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try a lightbox ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_(JavaScript)

There are various lightbox clones available which you could use with a iframe with a uploader form. Check out a comparison over here: http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/

Comment: Hi, many thanks for looking at my post. I've looked at 'Lightbox' & it looks a great piece of software. The problem I've got, is that I need to link the id of the main page to the images saved for that particualr record. Rather than trying to explain, please find a link to my page. http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/test.php. As you can see the user works through the page then at the bottom, they are asked if they want to upload any images. I'm using PHP to save the image to a folder because it was the only way I could think to link the main record and the linked images. kind regards

Comment: I think you already found a solution but you could link to the id of the main page right? if you open the iframe with a GET argument you could add the main id to the upload form in the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

As for as i know this was the very simple and less javascript popup window. This might help you. [less javascript popup box](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/downloads/lightbox.html)

Comment: Hi, many thanks for taking the time to send me this link, it's a great example. Kind regards